# How to slow down test execution in TestCafe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to check UI test execution written by another developer. It is too fast for my eyes and brain to catch what is happening.

How do I slow down the execution of tests in TestCafe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is to use setTestSpeed in beforeEach.  Here is a code snippet:

```
fixture`Test`
    .page`http://www.google.com`

    .before(async t => {
    })

    .beforeEach(async t => {
        await t.setTestSpeed(0.3)
        await t.maximizeWindow()
    })

test("hello", async t => {

});
```

Answer (score 8):

Found the answer after paying more attention to the [documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/debug.html#test-speed):

> TestCafe provides the capability to change test speed. Tests are executed at full speed with minimum delays between actions and assertions, which can make it hard to identify problems when a test is running.

> To slow down the test, use the --speed CLI flag. You can use values from 1 to 0.01.

```
testcafe chrome ./my-tests --speed 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I will just add the documentation here:
[Set Test Speed](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402963/guides/advanced-guides/speed-up-test-execution#set-test-speed)

A value of `1` represents the fastest emulation speed. This is the default `speed` value. A lower `speed` can be useful for debugging because it allows you to watch emulated actions on a screen, but it slows tests down.

For same example provided already:

```sh
testcafe chrome ./my-tests --speed 0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

we can add the following command while executing the test

```
--speed 0.08
```